# Defining a function in pandas to execute faster

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have observed that it takes 7-8 seconds to run my data if it is without function but if I define a function it hardly takes a second to execute the program.

In order to optimize the program, I opted for defining a function and put all my parameters inside that function but it is not printing my result and saving it in an excel file, not sure what exactly went wrong.
Although it executes without any error, it is neither printing the output nor giving me an excel file.

```
def data_manipulation(final_list):
  df_ma = pd.read_csv('State.csv')
  df_pa = pd.read_csv('Country.csv')
  final_list = pd.read_excel('Fruits_data.xlsx', sheet_name = 'aaa')

  act = glob.glob('current_*.csv')[0]     
  inact = glob.glob('Total_*.csv')[0]    
  df_dep = glob.glob('Vegetables_count_*.csv')[0]       
  df_net = glob.glob('Grains_*.csv')[0]    

  act_list = pd.read_csv(act, sheet_name = 'Fruits')
  inact_list= pd.read_csv(act, sheet_name = 'Vegetables')
  df_real= pd.read_csv(act)
  df_fake = pd.read_csv(df_net, sheet_name = 'Grains')
  new_merge = pd.merge(df_real, df_fake, on = 'Type', how = 'left')
  types = to_excel('new_merge.xlsx')
  print(new_merge.head(5))
  
  return data_manipulation
```

Comment: "I have observed that it takes 7-8 seconds to run my data if it is without function but if I define a function it hardly takes a second to execute the program." That doesn't make any sense

Comment: " but it is not printing my result and saving it in an excel file, not sure what exactly went wrong. Although it executes without any error, it is neither printing the output nor giving me an excel file." Um, did you *call the function*? I

Comment: There is a missing quote char in line `df_fake = pd.read_csv......`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga being new to python, I am not sure how to call a function. Can you help me with some source where I can find how to do it?

Comment: Too much File IO. Is this intended?

Comment: @Vishnudev not sure I get your question but if you mean that I have too many files for Input/output operation. Yes, is true... My data is coming from 6-7 different excel files

Comment: The parameter `final_list` doesn't seem to be needed as you're overwriting it with reading in an excel as a dataframe. So you could remove that. Calling the function (without the parameter): `data_manipulation()`. You probably want to save the result of the function call to a variable so you can do something with it at a later point: `some_variable = data_manipulation()`

Comment: @BasvanderLinden so at the top, I will edit  it as follows:                                               def data_manipulation():           
 code
 code
 new_merge = data_manipulation()